# Как нарисовать линию от точки до точки?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Позиция обьекта линии расположен в другой точке, как протянуть линию в другую часть?
Так не работает:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;


public class Calculating : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float X;
    public float Y;

    public float X2;
    public float Y2;
    public float Offset;

    public LineRenderer Line;

    public Transform FirstPoint;
    public Transform SecondPoint;

    private void Start()
    {
        CalculatingFunc();
    }

    void CalculatingFunc()
    {
        FirstPoint.position += new Vector3(X * Offset, Y * Offset, 0);
        SecondPoint.position += new Vector3(X2 * Offset, Y2 * Offset, 0);
        Line.transform.position = FirstPoint.position;
        Line.SetPosition(1, SecondPoint.posi);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как рисуется сам график?

Comment: @Andrew добавил

Comment: Что-то я не вижу здесь кода который рисует саму шкалу графика

Comment: @Andrew Line.SetPosition.
Если сделать в первый индекс первую точку, а во второй вторую, то все равно он неправильно рисует.

Comment: это не рисование шкалы. Это рисование некоей неясной линии. А я просил код рисующий шкалу. Твоя же шкала состоит из приблизительно 32 линий, около 20 чисел и еще 2х символов

Answer (score 0):

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]

public class Calculating : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] Vector2[] _positions = new Vector2[2];
    [SerializeField] Vector2 _offset;
    private LineRenderer _line;

    private void Awake () {
        _line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        _line.useWorldSpace = false;
        _line.transform.localPosition = _offset;
        _line.positionCount = _positions.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < _positions.Length; i++)
            _line.SetPosition(i, _positions[i]);
    }
}
```